# moveRows with NSFetchedResultsController bug

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a bug in here somewhere and I can not find it so I am hoping your keen eyes will!

I am using a FRC with a tableView. the FRC is section sorted by keyPath and then sorted by "displayOrder" - the usual.

The Details "displayOrder" in each section start at 1 so when I insert an item, in another method, it goes to index 0 of the section.

I want to loop through the affected section(s) and re-assign the "displayOrder" starting at 1.

During re-order, the code works for:
Re-ordering within the any section AS LONG AS the re-ordered cell moves up and not down.

Code does not work for... clicking on a cell but not moving it.. the code changes the order for some reason thus changing the order of the cells.  - when I click a cell, it along with the other cells above it in the same section re-order.

I used to have this working and I don't know what happened.

Thanks for any help.

-Edited-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

NSError *error = nil;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

TheDetail *fromThing = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
TheDetail *toThing = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:toIndexPath];

NSPredicate *catetgoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipToTheCategory.name == %@", fromThing.relationshipToTheCategory.name];

NSMutableArray *allThings = [[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:catetgoryPredicate] mutableCopy];

NSPredicate *fromPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipToTheSection.name == %@", fromThing.relationshipToTheSection.name];
NSPredicate *toPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipToTheSection.name == %@", toThing.relationshipToTheSection.name];

[allThings removeObject:fromThing];
[allThings insertObject:fromThing atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

//if the sections are NOT the same, reorder by section otherwise reorder the one section
if (![fromThing.relationshipToTheSection.name isEqual:toThing.relationshipToTheSection.name]) {

    //Change the from index section's relationship and save, then grab all objects in sections and re-order
    [fromThing setRelationshipToTheSection:toThing.relationshipToTheSection];

    if ([context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"The setting section save was successful!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"The setting section save was not successful: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSMutableArray *fromThings = [[allThings  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fromPredicate]mutableCopy];
    NSInteger i = 1;
    for (TheDetail *fromD in fromThings) {
        [fromD setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
        i++;

    }
    //reset displayOrder Count, the re-order the other section
    i = 1;
    NSMutableArray *toThings = [[allThings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:toPredicate]mutableCopy];
    for (TheDetail *toD in toThings) {
        [toD setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
        i++;

    }
} else {
    NSMutableArray *fromThings = [[allThings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fromPredicate]mutableCopy];
    NSInteger i = 1;
    for (TheDetail *fromD in fromThings) {
        [fromD setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
        i++;
    }
}
if ([context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"The save was successful!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"The save was not successful: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

FRC

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
{
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self appDelegate]managedObjectContext];

//Construct the fetchResquest
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *detail = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TheDetail"    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:detail];

//Add predicate 
NSString *category = @"1";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipToTheCategory == %@", category];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

//Add sort descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"relationshipToTheSection.displayOrder" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"displayOrder" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor2, sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


//Set fetchedResultsController
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"relationshipToTheSection.name" cacheName:@"Root"];
NSError *error = nil;


self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

New Error

```
    Section *toSection = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][[toIndexPath section]];

NSString *toSectionName = [[[toSection objects] lastObject] name];
```

Here I get the error in the IB "No visible @interface for "DSection" declares the selector 'objects'.

Comment: You are adding different errors to a single question.  That is not the way you should be doing this.  Accept this answer that a lot of effort was put into and then create a new question.  Otherwise you might as well just hire me to write your app.

Comment: oh. Sorry. Noob here.

Comment: This was an error from your code. Although I do appreciate your valiant work, my original problem still exists.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you still have an issue then it is not in the code I provided to you.  Perhaps look and see if you have a redraw issue or an issue in your `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods.

Comment: Can you tell me what "Section" means in the code you eloquently provided?  I don't have anything named that in my .h or .m file and it's not recognizing it.  Thanks

Comment: You could follow the code in the documentation and see that it is a `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>`.  I am not surprised there are errors in the code. It was written in a web browser without access to **your** code or Xcode.  Asking questions includes the expectations that you understand the language and how to read its documentation.

Comment: Sorry I did not meet the expectations. I thought this was a place of learning. I must have been mistaken. First, I have been reading the documentation and haven't been getting anywhere and yes I recognized this as an id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> before you said anything and was already implementing it and trying to make it work. I thought maybe you knew something I didn't and was asking for clarification. Secondly, if I knew what I needed to know I wouldn't be here asking. Thank you again for you efforts.

Comment: This is a place of learning as opposed to a place of "write it for me.".  Learning requires a solid two way dialog.  There is a difference between "What is section" and "I have been reading the documentation and I can't figure out what section is."  One gets the helper annoyed the other does not. I would suggest reviewing the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of SO so that you can get the most out of the free help you are receiving.

Answer (score 12):

1. Don't remove yourself as the delegate for the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  That is against the intended design of that class.  If that is "helping" then it is masking a real problem.
2. Don't call `-performFetch;` from this method.  The `NSFetchedResultsController` will detect the changes and tell your delegate about them.
3. Don't call `-reloadData` from this method.  Let the delegate methods of `NSFetchedResultsController` do the reordering.
4. **Always, always, always** capture the error on a core data save.  Even though you really don't need to save here (this is a bad time to block the UI with a save), you should **ALWAYS** capture the error and then watch for the result otherwise errors are hidden.
5. It is not clear what the `-save:` is doing.  You haven't changed anything by the point of that save.

So that is a lot of work you are doing that you don't need to do.  You are fighting the framework and making things harder.

Your reordering logic is more complicated than it needs to be, *I think*.  It would help to see the `NSFetchedResultsController` initialization as well.  But I am guessing you have sections based on `name` and then order by `displayOrder`.  If that is the case this code can be a lot cleaner which would then make the issue more apparent.

My question to you is, are you checking this with breakpoints?  Is this code firing when a row doesn't get actually moved?  Should you check to see if your `toIndexPath` and `fromIndexPath` are equal?

### Update

You do not need to save your context here. This is a UI method, saving causes delays which will make the UI slow to respond.  **Save later.**

You do not need to run a NSFetchRequest here.  That also hits disk and causes delays in the UI.  Every piece of information that you need is already in memory inside of your `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Use the existing object relationships to retrieve the data you are needing to make your decisions.

Calling entities `The*` is against Objective-C naming conventions.  Words like "the", "is", "are" do not belong in entity or class names.

Consider this version of your code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self fetchedResultsController] managedObjectContext];

    TheDetail *fromThing = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
    Section *toSection = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][[toIndexPath section]];

    NSString *toSectionName = [[[toSection objects] lastObject] name];
    NSString *fromSectionName = [[fromThing relationshipToTheSection] name];
    if ([toSectionName isEqualToString:fromSectionName]) {
        //Same section, easy reorder

        //Move the object
        NSMutableArray *sectionObjects = [[[[self fetchedResultsController] sections][[fromIndexPath section]] objects] mutableCopy];
        [sectionObjects removeObject:fromThing];
        [sectionObjects insertObject:fromThing atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

        //Reorder
        NSInteger index = 1;
        for (TheDetail *thing in sectionObjects) {
            [thing setValue:@(index) forKey:@"displayOrder"];
        }

        return; //Early return to keep code on the left margin
    }

    NSMutableArray *sectionObjects = [[[[self fetchedResultsController] sections][[fromIndexPath section]] objects] mutableCopy];
    [sectionObjects removeObject:fromThing];

    //Reorder
    NSInteger index = 1;
    for (TheDetail *thing in sectionObjects) {
        [thing setValue:@(index) forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }

    if ([[toSection numberOfObjects] count] == 0) {
        [fromThing setValue:@(0) forKey:@"displayOrder"];
        //How do you determine the name?
        return;
    }

    sectionObjects = [[toSection objects] mutableCopy];
    [sectionObjects insertObject:fromThing atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];

    //Reorder
    NSInteger index = 1;
    for (TheDetail *thing in sectionObjects) {
        [thing setValue:@(index) forKey:@"displayOrder"];
    }
}
```

There is no fetching and no saving.  We are working with only what is in memory already so it is **VERY** fast.  This should be C&P-able except for one of the comments I left in.

Comment: Thanks Marcus! Followed every step and it is working perfect now.

Comment: I'll work on the reordering logic.  I think it ended up complicated because of the problems I kept running into.

Comment: As far as the section sorting goes: I am sorting through a relationship name and then "displayOrder".

Comment: Turns out it is not working perfect.  when moving cell #1 to the #4 position and clicking "done". Looks good. But, when I select the #4 cell it treats it like I tapped the #1 cell. then when the data reloads the cells aren't in the proper order anymore.  suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and add the new code. If you are getting those kinds of results it smells like an off by one (or more) error. It would help to answer the questions I posed as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far.  Sorry I forgot to answer the posed questions. Yes I am checking with breakpoints and yes I am checking to make sure the sections are reflecting the correct section title. (although I deleted the NSLogs once I confirmed they were working. I will add the FRC Initialization too.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time helping with this.  I really appreciate it. I changed the entity names, thank you for informing me.  the answer to your question in regards to section name determination is it's own Entity now named "DSection" "name".  It has a relationship to the Detail.  I am getting a small error in the IB. I'll edit the code above.  Thanks.